# Loops of different sizes

Tags: xy-pic

In xy-pic we can draw a loop in this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}

$$\xymatrix{a\ar@(dr,ur)}$$

\end{\document}
```

My question is how to draw a bigger loop around this loop, and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using the more modern and versatile [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package instead of `xy` is an option, this can be easily done:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A
\arrow[
  out=105,
  in=75,
  loop,
  distance=0.5cm]
\arrow[
  out=120,
  in=60,
  loop,
  distance=1cm]
\arrow[
  out=130,
  in=50,
  loop,
  distance=1.5cm]
\arrow[
  out=-105,
  in=-75,
  loop,
  distance=0.5cm]
\arrow[
  out=-120,
  in=-60,
  loop,
  distance=1cm]
\arrow[
  out=-130,
  in=-50,
  loop,
  distance=1.5cm]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just two questions: (1) what does the parameter distance do, exactly?, and (2) when I put the \begin{tikzcd}...\end{tikzcd} inside a `\[...\]`, the distance between the last line of a paragraph and the top of the diagram is too big; I'd like that gap to be more like when I insert a diagram with xy-pic. How can I do that?

Comment: @QuiqueRuiz You're welcome! (1) The `distance` key sets the values for `min distance` and `max distance` which control the diatnce between the start and target coordinates (for a complete description, please refer to pages 755 and 736 of the pgfmanual). (2) Use the overlay key for the outer loop, as in `\arrow[
  out=130,
  in=50,
  loop,
  distance=1.5cm,overlay]` (in my exmaple code). If this doesn't solve the problem, the best thing to do would be to open a fresh new question with a MWE illustrating the undesired behaviour.