# making loops longer with \xymatrix

Tags: xymatrix

I am wondering if I can put all the loops on the left side of "u" by changing the length of loops in the following graph. (keep working in `\xymatrix`) (see the photo)

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix  @=220pt  { 
  u \ar@/^3.5pc/@{}[r]^{\alpha_{d(u, v)}} |{\SelectTips{cm}{}\object@{>}}  \ar@/^2.4pc /@{.>}[r] |{\SelectTips{cm}{}\object@{>}} \ar@/^1.0 pc/[r]^{\alpha_{1}} |{\SelectTips{cm}{}\object@{>}} \ar@{.}@(l,d) \ar@(ur,dr)^{\gamma_{1}} \ar@(r,d)^{\gamma_{2}} \ar@(dr,dl)^{\gamma_{3}} 
\ar@(l,u)^{\gamma_{d(u, u)}}
        &
v   \ar@/^1.0 pc/[l]^{\beta_1}|{\SelectTips{cm}{}\object@{>}}   \ar@/^2.5pc /@{.>}[l] |{\SelectTips{cm}{}\object@{>}}  \ar@/^3.5pc/[l]^{\beta_{d(v, u)}} |{\SelectTips{cm}{}\object@{>}}
\ar@{.}@(l,d) \ar@(ur,dr)^{\tau_{1}} \ar@(r,d)^{\tau_{2}} \ar@(dr,dl)^{\tau_{3}} 
 \ar@(l,u) ^(0.6) {\tau_{d(v, v)}}  }   
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: Please add a sketch so we can *see* what the result should look like

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  I added a photo. Thanks.

Comment: If you can switch to tikz-cd: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208905/loops-of-different-sizes

Comment: I do not want to switch to Tikz-cd, so I am wondering if I can write only loops with Tikz-cd without changing the other part of the graph, which is written with \xymatrix.